# In bash, what does <<< is used for?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I've look for documentation about this sign **<<<** but i can't find any good explanation.

Here is an example:

```
IFS=';' read -ra ADDR <<< "allo;hi;salut"
```

What does this line do ? and specificaly what does **<<<** do in this line?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's used to create a [Here String](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html)